# Scene phase not initialized project nextJS

Tags: reactjs, typescript, next.js, phaser-framework

The phase does not initialize when I start the project.
this is all the dependencies that I'm using the project

- "@nextui-org/react": "^1.0.0-beta.9"
- "@reduxjs/toolkit": "^1.8.3",
- "immer": "^9.0.15",
- "next": "12.2.3",
- "phaser": "^3.55.2",
- "react":"17.0.2",
- "react-dom": "17.0.2",
- "react-redux": "^8.0.2",
- "styled-components": "^5.3.5",
- "swiper": "^8.3.1"

_app.tsx

```
import type { AppProps } from 'next/app'
import dynamic from 'next/dynamic'
import Head from 'next/head'
import { Fragment } from 'react'
import GlobalStyles from '../styles/Globals'

function MyApp({ Component, pageProps }: AppProps) {
  const PhaserGameNoSSR = dynamic(() => import('../phaser'), {
    ssr: false,
  })

  return (
    <Fragment>
      <Head>
        <title>project</title>
        <meta name="description" content="Metaverse Bits Website" />
      </Head>
      <GlobalStyles />
      <PhaserGameNoSSR />
      <Component {...pageProps} />
    </Fragment>
  )
}

export default MyApp
```

phaseGame.tsx

```
import { useRef } from 'react'
import { useGame } from '../hooks/useGame'
import { gameConfig } from './phaserConfig'

function PhaserGame() {
  const parentEl = useRef<HTMLDivElement>(null)
  useGame(gameConfig, parentEl)

  return <div ref={parentEl} id="phaser-container" />
}

export default PhaserGame
```

Config phase game config

```
import { Types } from 'phaser'
import Background from '../scenes/background'
import { Bootstrap } from '../scenes/bootstrap'

export const gameConfig: Types.Core.GameConfig = {
  title: 'project',
  type: Phaser.AUTO,
  pixelArt: true,
  scale: {
    mode: Phaser.Scale.ScaleModes.RESIZE,
    width: window.innerWidth,
    height: window.innerHeight,
  },
  physics: {
    default: 'arcade',
    arcade: {
      gravity: { y: 0 },
      debug: false,
    },
  },
  autoFocus: true,
  scene: [Bootstrap, Background],
}
```

first scene background

```
import Phaser from 'phaser'

export default class Background extends Phaser.Scene {
  private backdropKey!: string

  constructor() {
    super('background')
  }

  create() {
    const sceneHeight = this.cameras.main.height
    const sceneWidth = this.cameras.main.width

    this.backdropKey = 'background_initial'

    const backdropImage = this.add.image(sceneWidth / 2, sceneHeight / 2, this.backdropKey)
    const scale = Math.max(sceneWidth / backdropImage.width, sceneHeight / backdropImage.height)
    backdropImage.setScale(scale).setScrollFactor(0)
  }
}
```

And config init phase scene

```
import { Scene } from 'phaser'

export class Bootstrap extends Scene {
  constructor() {
    super('bootstrap')
  }

  preload() {
    this.load.image('background_initial', 'assets/background.png')
  }
  create(): void {
    console.log('launched')
  }

  private launchBackground() {
    this.scene.launch('background')
  }

  changeBackgroundMode() {
    this.scene.stop('background')
  }
}
```

Comment: btw.: i noticed the **parent** - Element, is not defined in the `config`, I don't think it is the whole solution, but might help.

Comment: I have one question, how are you starting the Phaser game _(calling `new Phaser.Game(...)`)_